# Y axis beginning value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I want to set the Y axis beginning value equal to `1e-20`, but MATLAB always gives zero. My variable, which is `meanerror` has a value of `1e-15`. So MATLAB's distances between the Y axis values are very big and whatever I do, I don't see `1e-15` in this graph.
Actually,I want to see `1e-15` after beginning any value which is not zero on Y axis. May be between `1e-20` (beginning value) and `1e-10`.
How can I do that ?

Here is the code :

```
plot(x,meanerror,'Color','k');
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0]);
set(gca,'xlim',[0 3e5]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','','1E+5','','2E+5','','3E+5'});
set(gca,'ylim',[1e-20 1e3]);
```

Here is the graph:
[image]

Comment: try using a `logplot` instead of a regular plot

Comment: I think you want [`semilogy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogy.html) or potentially [`loglog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html) if your x-data also spans many orders of magnitude.

Comment: I would like to thank @TroyHaskin for providing help.
I write upgraded code for helping to other people which is worked properly with same variable.I can show all power of 10 values in this graph.
'semilogy(x,meanerror);
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0]);'